# Why will my django manytomany through only allow access through related_name?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I have these models

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField('Item', through='CollectionItem', related_name='collection_items')
    ...

class Item(models.Model):
    ...

class CollectionItem(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    extra_stuff = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Am i thinking about this the wrong way or should i be able to access the 'through' objects related to a collection, using

```
collection = get_object_or_404(Collection, pk=1)
collection.collectionitem_set.all()
```

As i'm just getting an an attribute error?

However I am am able to access them through the related_name

```
collection = get_object_or_404(Collection, pk=1)
collection.collection_items.all()
```

Am i missing something really obvious? Why doesn't using 'collectionitem_set' work?

***EDIT***

Just noticed an important omission, which is why collection.collection_items.all() works. I had the same related_name set on the CollectionItem as well

```
class CollectionItem(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, related_name='collection_items')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    extra_stuff = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Once i've removed that, neither way works.

Comment: collection.collectionitem_set.all() <-- where is that _set thing supposed to come from? You haven't defined it anywhere...

Comment: @Dr.Elch no, django automatically creates those are the reverse end of a Foreignkey... here that would be the `collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection)` on the `CollectionItem` 'through' model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't repeat that. Using your models, with additional `name` fields:

```
>>> from models import Collection, Item, CollectionItem
>>> c = Collection.objects.create(name='coll1')
>>> c.collectionitem_set.all()
[]
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, from my admittedly limited knowlegde of django, i'd expect it to work. But for some reason it's not. From attempting to solve this this morning i've read that there should be in a table in my db representing this join. But i can't see one? Could this be the issue?

Comment: My mistake. This appears to have been caused by my lack of understanding of the use of 'related_name'. I'm presuming that explicitly stating the related name for the reverse on CollectionItem, removes the ability to access the items through collection.collectionitem_set?

Comment: Yes. collectionitem_set is just the default related_name: if you set it explicitly, you override that default.

Comment: Ahhh i see, that explains it then. Thanks again.